# How to store MySQL database in Google App Engine Cloud SQL?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Im doing a project in Android in my College. I have a MySql database and i need to move this database in to Google Cloud Sql from accessing from my Android app. HOw can i achieve this?

i have only 3 tables in my database. can any one tell me a step by step procedure to handle this. i saw something from [google app engine docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/). i can't understand it.

im using servlet.

i need anyones guiding to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is too broad. I would suggest going step by step based on answer added by @Shay. Then post questions on problems you face or specific queries around each topic. You will learn much more too that way!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad but here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Create a Cloud SQL account
2. Import the data and scheme to it (Cloud SQL support import)
3. Create an AppEngine Application
4. Allow the AppEngine app id access to the Cloud SQL
5. Create an application that android can access which talk to your cloud sql